# WPF: Cut-off corner of border

Tags: c#, wpf, border

How might I make a single `cutted-off` (upper-right) corner of a border in WPF; similar to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shanemo/archive/2008/08/11/billy-hollis-on-getting-smart-with-wpf.aspx)?

Comment: Check this link- [Cutt-off corner of border][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459762/wpf-cut-corner-element

Comment: What is the Generic.xaml in your link? Is it Resource Dictionary (WPF) Item?

Comment: yes Generic is a resource Dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this can help you

```
<Grid Background="#FF4E7BF5" Width="250" Height="250">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <!--This RectangleGeometry will show Grid body-->
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,250,250"/>

            <!--This PathGeometry will cut RectangleGeometry, cut-off right top-->
            <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="230,0">
                            <LineSegment Point="250,0"/>
                            <LineSegment Point="250,20"/>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>

            <!--This PathGeometry will cut RectangleGeometry, cut-of left bottom-->
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,230">
                        <LineSegment Point="0,250"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="20,250"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Grid.Clip>
</Grid>
```

Effect of this code

[image]